# Spatialite return XY coordinate in Double Precision

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I'm trying to return the first vertice of polyline in QspatiaLite. 
The function x() is used, but it returns integer coordinate value. 
How to return the coordinate value in double precision? 
This is my query and result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the printf function to format the output:

```
SELECT id, AsText(StartPoint(Geometry), printf("%.02f", ST_X(PointN(Geometry,1))) FROM shp_lane;
```